# Filter default list view by sharepoint user group using out of the box feature

Tags: list, sharepoint, listitem

I have a list which I need to filter based on the group of currently logged-in users using an out-of-the-box feature.

For example: I created a list named "test".

Now I have created 3 folders in the `test` list using the names of a SharePoint User Group and added 1 item in each. Then I add that list web-part to another page.

I want to display, for example, to "user1" only the folder "user1" along with its item.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the relevant parts of your code, as well as any errors you are encountering.

Comment: If you are using a column that holds the user info, you can set your view to filter that column with [Me] - which would be for the current user.